# Why are all the TreeNodes of the tree re-rendered when one of them is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, tree, antd

I have a custom antd Tree component and noticed using the Google React Developer Tools extension that all the TreeNode are updated when I click on one arbitrary TreeNode (even a leaf).
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that clicking in one of the TreeNodes is updating the internal React State, and that makes it update the whole component.

With some ammount of code i would be able to confirm that or not.
Can you please answer as solved if this helped you in any way?
Or you might add additional doubts.

Comment: I don't know how to check what you're suggesting...
I realised this problem when I tried to implement drag & drop in this component, since it generated a lot of TreeNode updates while dragging, making it unusable due to too much lagging.
I don't understand while it behaves like this, I'm quite new do React.

Comment: it's quite easy to notice/reproduce with one of their example:
https://ant.design/components/tree/
Any idea if this Tree component behaves normally ?, all those updates make it quickly unusable to me, can't imagine this is by designed...

Comment: I think it's by design, it seems that it updates all of the level in the three when some checkbox is clicked.